# using TOTP Microsoft authenticator for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, two-factor-authentication

We already have a single authentication process using Active Directory for our home made web sites (simple login and password). Our AD is also on Azure (everything is synchronized).

Now we want 2 factors authentification using this: (Microsoft Authenticator) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/account/authenticator

I've been searching for an exemple for a while, but most of the tutorials I found are about MVC CORE; **I'm not using core**, just regular MVC .Net Framework. Furthermore, the only tutorials I found using .Net framework were for Google authenticator, not Microsoft's one.

The intended behavior would be the same as when I connect to office 365, first I enter my password in the web site, then I receive a notification on my cell phone (for exemple), by approving the connection, I can have access to web content.

I'm still trying to figure out if this is even allowed, is Microsoft Authenticator only meant to be used for Microsoft developers or can we random developers use this app for our 2FA needs? Or is there a way to trigger the office 365 authentication windows?

If yes, they don't seem eager to share any code or tutorial for MVC .net Framework. (I'm still searching)

**EDIT for comments:**

Microsoft auth .Net Core documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Google auth with .Net framework documentation:

https://medium.com/@henryhdelgado/2fa-with-google-authenticator-in-asp-mvc-4788c79c47

**EDIT / Solution :**

In case someone didn't borther reading the answer's comments, here's what I was actually looking for : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp

Comment: First question, Is there a product requirement for the usage of .Net Core vs .Net Framework? 
Can you provide a link to your referenced documentation/tutorial?
Where are your user's being stored? if they're in Active Directory, you can directly call your AD host and trigger the MFA prompt. 

The AD host will determine the answer to this question.

Comment: @Seeds See my edit, yes, all my user are in AD. Calling my Ad Host to trigger the MFA prompt would be FANTASTIC !!! I don't know how though, I could show you the code I use to log a user (not sure it would help)

Comment: To Confirm, are we talking Microsoft AD on a Windows machine? or Azure cloud AD? or another type of AD (this impacts which library/method).

Comment: @Seeds Microsoft Active Directory that we host here in our buildings, with a domain name and folders and thousands of users

Comment: Just saw that we are also on azure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: **you don't need to do anything** (provided that your application authenticates users using OIDC, which it will do if you're using *Azure Active Directory* or Office 365 with your application). Just flip the switch in your organization's O365 or AAD settings to require TOTP/2FA.

However, if your application is actually authenticating against on-prem AD (whether using Kerberos via the browser shell, or with "Forms authentication") and you can't make your web-application authenticate against AAD/O365 (*not* on-prem AD) and you don't have AD Federation working, then you're in for a world of pain because getting on-prem 2FA working is a massive undertaking that requires just as much work from your sysadmins as it does from you (and then your question would be closed for being "too broad", sorry!)

---

Authenticating against AAD/O365 can be done using any OIDC client library, though Microsoft does make a purpose-built library available on NuGet which works in .NET Framework applications in addition to .NET Core: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/ (formerly https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/ )

---

"Azure Active Directory" (AAD) is a misnomer btw, as it has very little to do with on-prem Active Directory. That said, if you're using Office 365 within your enterprise then you will already have AAD up-and-running - just be aware that it's still completely unrelated to Active Directory (as far as technology is concerned).

Using AAD/O365 for SSO basically means using OIDC (whereas on-prem AD is Kerberos, not OIDC) - so any OIDC library can be used with AAD/O365. The TOTP/2FA part is handled entirely by AAD/O365 so you don't actually need to do anything in your own application to handle TOTP/2FA.

Comment: My home made web apps are hosted by our local IIS server, and I currently use DirectoryEntry class to authenticate user, it just verify if the user and password matches like a form authentication as you say... But do you think that, if I just add the library I could handle this ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier oooooh, no. If you're using `DirectoryEntry` you're doing it wrong anyway (instead you _should_ be using AD SPN impersonation or delegation - **because no program should be handling AD user credentials!**) - as you'll need to switch to OIDC you'll have to basically reimplement your web-app's entire authX system - have fun! You're looking at _at least_ a couple weeks' worth of learning how ASP.NET's auth system works and then faceplant with OIDC and that's before you'll get to write any code. You should consider using this as an opportunity to migrate to ASP.NET Core, imo.

Comment: Omg... this will be taking forever. Well, when it's time to evolve. One last question, when I use my unsafe `DirectoryEntry` technique, I can have access other informations that are already well stored and important like, where the user work, what's is phone number. I suppose this is also possible with OICD ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yes, but only with user-consent - but that's already handled as part of OAuth2 (which is part of OIDC): your application will request access to specific "scopes" (e.g. user-files, user's personal info, etc) and the user gets to choose whether or not to grant your application _consent_ or not (but if this is an internal app, the sysadmins will set-up default permissions for everyone).

Comment: You set me on the right track, I found this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp not sure but I think this is what I'm aiming for

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Yes, that article looks to be what you're looking for.